# how to toggle anchor tag text in jquery

Tags: jquery

i want to toggle anchor tag text, i have an anchor tag within div, when user clicks on reply, comment box get open and text should change into close and vice versa but problem is that after text getting change to close, text remain become close nd toggle between show nd hide works clearly...

```
<a id="reply" href="#">reply</a>
<div id="replyuser" style=" position:absolute;">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" CssClass="txtbox" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnreply" Text="send" runat="server" CssClass="btn" />
</div>
```

jquery is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#replyuser").hide();

    $("#reply").click(function() {
        $("#replyuser").toggle(function() {
            $("#reply").text("close");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#replyuser").hide();

                $("#reply").click(function() {

                    $("#replyuser").toggle(function(e) {
                           $(this).is(":visible") ? $("#reply").text("close") : $("#reply").text("reply");                         
                    });

                });
            });
```

$(this) is reference to $("#replyuser") control [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302618/jquery-and-this-object) and :visible is selector for visible controls (surprised a :)). 
So logicly .is checks if $("#replyuser") is visible.

Comment: but one thing sir will you please tell me that concatenation function working  $(this).is(":visible") ? $("#reply").text("close") : $("#reply").text("reply");

Comment: @elrado better if you explain your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing the text on click:

You are in context of a button then try refering it with `$(this)` when it gets a click event then toggle the `#reply` div and check for the text. If this has the text `reply` change it to `close`.

#### Put this in the css:

```
#replyuser {
    display:none;
}
```

#### Use this script then:

```
$("#reply").click(function() {
   $("#replyuser").toggle();
   ($(this).text() === "reply") ? $(this).text("close") : $(this).text("reply");
});
```

#### [Final Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BYcfv/2/)

Comment: thanks sir its working with text, but i also want toggle show hide accordingly with text

Comment: sorry sir by mistake i did downvote extremly sorry, i have undo that

Comment: Its find no issues but i just updated the code in the answer. Is this working fine for you? let me know plz.

Comment: by doing little changes in your given code accordng to the changes suggested by elrado its now working thanks a lot

Comment: yeah you have to hide it first, via css it can be achieved `#replyuser{display:none;}`

Comment: Okay great keep it up! and Good Luck. `:P`

Comment: sir one last thing that i also asked with elrado will u please elaborate concatenation function and how it works

Comment: See that is not concatenation its a shorter way of `if(condition){true}else{false}`, This is called ternary operator `(condition) ? true : false;` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F: