# scope of "this" in jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I faced a very interesting issue today which many of you might find elementary but since I am just learning to use jQuery, I am interested to know how this works.

I have two arrays and I'm iterating through the elements of array. One array is `arrAllDetailsConstantData` and the other one is `arrAllDetails`. I want to **compare** using **arrAllDetailsConstantData**  and **update** using **arrAllDetails**.

I am using nested loops. But what is happening is that while updating array **arrAllDetails**, array **arrAllDetailsConstantData** is also getting updated. I assume this is somehow related to scope of parent this (though I am just guessing). Can you please help me with this?

Here is my code:

```
$.each(privateVariables.arrAllDetailsConstantData, function() {
    if (this.AssociationId == value && this.uniqueChargeAttr == uniqueChargeAttr) {

        if (this.Units == $("#txtUnits").val() &&
            this.Modifier1 == $("#txtModifier1").val() &&
            this.Modifier2 == $("#txtModifier2").val() &&
            this.Modifier3 == $("#txtModifier3").val() &&
            this.Modifier4 == $("#txtModifier4").val() &&
            this.DxOption == $("#ddlDxOption").val() &&
            this.DxCode1 == $("#txtDx1").val() &&
            this.DxCode2 == $("#txtDx2").val() &&
            this.DxCode3 == $("#txtDx3").val() &&
            this.DxCode4 == $("#txtDx4").val()) {

        } else {
            $.each(arrAllDetails, function() {
                if (this.AssociationId == value && this.uniqueChargeAttr == uniqueChargeAttr) {
                    this.ActionType = "M";
                    this.CptName = $("#lblCptDesc").text();
                    this.CptDesc = $("#lblCptDesc").text();
                    this.Units = $("#txtUnits").val();
                    this.Modifier1 = $("#txtModifier1").val();
                    this.Modifier2 = $("#txtModifier2").val();
                    this.Modifier3 = $("#txtModifier3").val();
                    this.Modifier4 = $("#txtModifier4").val();
                    this.DxOption = $("#ddlDxOption").val();
                    this.DxCode1 = $("#txtDx1").val();
                    this.DxCode2 = $("#txtDx2").val();
                    this.DxCode3 = $("#txtDx3").val();
                    this.DxCode4 = $("#txtDx4").val();

                    privateVariables.arrActionData.push(this);

                }
            });
        }
    }
});

// test code ends
```

Comment: _this_ inside jQuery callback functions refers to iterated element

Comment: But then why both arrays are getting updated.. Only arrAllDetails should be updated in that case.

Comment: `privateVariables.arrActionData.push(this);` here you add element from `arrAllDetails` to `privateVariables.arrActionData` so when you update this element - values changes in all arrays, because in array saved just reference to the same object

Comment: But I didnt perform any operation on arrAllDetailsConstantData. Why was the object pushed into this array

Comment: you should check how you fill `privateVariables.arrAllDetailsConstantData` and `arrAllDetails`

Comment: @Grundy They are filled using the same source.

Comment: so you can use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) as suggest @Remi

Comment: @Grundy .slice() didnt work as expected. Still I am getting same results.

Comment: yep :-) seems you need deepclone object in array see a bit more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, the jQuery's `this` refers to the calling element.

In a `$.each`, this refers to the **iterated element**.

So, in your first loop : `$.each(privateVariables.arrAllDetailsConstantData, function() {});`, `this` will be the **currently looping element** of your `arrAllDetailsConstantData` array.

In the second loop, `this` will be the **currently looping element** of your `arrAllDetails` array.

- Secondly, we need the arrays creation's code.

Don't forget, in many languages, that if you use this `arrAllDetailsConstantData = arrAllDetails`, the pointer reference to those two object are pointing to **the same memory range**.

In this case, use `arrAllDetailsConstantData = arrAllDetails.slice();` from `Array.prototype.slice`.

Comment: Will using .slice make the array point to another location in memory?

Comment: `.slice()` prototype function will create a "clone" of your array, but they will be **different** objects yes

Comment: This is how the arrays are populated.
 arrAllDetails = response.aaData;
 privateVariables.arrAllDetailsConstantData = response.aaData;

Comment: @GauravSachdeva as say @Remi just `arrAllDetails = response.aaData.slice();`

Comment: You can find some informations about how `.slice()` works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Comment: So I can probably use something like this : 
 arrAllDetails = response.aaData;
 privateVariables.arrAllDetailsConstantData = arrAllDetails.slice();
    Am I correct?

Comment: `arrAllDetails = response.aaData.slice();` and `privateVariables.arrAllDetailsConstantData = arrAllDetails.slice();` yes

Comment: @GauravSachdeva not matter on what array you apply _slice_ :-)

Comment: Just try to use `.slice()` everytime you want to "clone" an `Array` :)

Comment: I just tried to use .slice(). It doesn't help..  :( 
And .clone() doesn't let me proceed neither does it give any exception.

Comment: Can you past your code to a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ? It's hard to help without all the code here.

Comment: @RémiDelhaye New to JS Fiddle but I pasted my code here.. http://jsfiddle.net/8fqmv4yc/

Comment: @GauravSachdeva can you please try this : http://jsfiddle.net/ebuk5/157/ Moreover, i need to know how your `privateVariables.arrActionData` array is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

for the scope of "this" you can check out [JQuery and 'this' object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302618/jquery-and-this-object/1302681#1302681)

As for your code: You need to add how you created the two arrays in the first place.

Based on your code they seem to be created by using the same elements (so arrDetails seems to be a subset of the objects in arrAllDetails). Something in the way of

```
$.each(arrDetails, function() {arrAllDetails.push(this); });
```

or by simply assinging:

```
arrDetails = arrAllDetails;
```

If that is the case then the object within the arrays are actually the SAME. So editing the element in one array will also edit it in the other array (they point to the same object in memory).

I am not sure what you try to accomplish, but if you want the objects to be different you need to clone the entries so they are seperate objects instead of just using them.

Apart from that you basic understanding from this (it applies to the closest scope) is correct, but overridden by other issues.

Comment: The answer you linked to about jQuery and the 'this' object talks about jQuery event handlers involving a DOM element. That's not really relevant here...in jQuery's `each` function, `this` simply refers to the current item in the array.

Comment: Yes, U r right. Both arrays are populated using the same source. I have to maintain two array to detect any changes made in UI fields at run time. Any suggestions how can I avoid updating the array arrAllDetailsConstantData

Comment: You can "clone" the array by using: http://api.jquery.com/clone/ that will create a complete separate set.

Comment: @Niko  .clone() doesn't let me proceed neither does it give any exception.

Comment: @Niko any suggesstions??

Comment: sorry, without seeing more of the code I cannot really help you. You really should try to clone each item in the array: $.each(arrDetails, function() {arrAllDetails.push($.clone(this,true)); });
or if that doe snot work (which it should), try retrieving the data two times or detect the changes in the ui with a different mehtod (i.e. setting the input fields to .addClass('changed') in the onChange event).

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript `this` refers to the owner of a function-execution. It is not always easy to know what the owner actually is. With scoping on HTML-Elements, `this` usually refers to the elements itself. Inside an iteration (like `$.each(data, function)`) `this` refers to the item, that is iterated over.

You use `this` in 2 different contexts. Each time in another iteration.

```
$.each(privateVariables.arrAllDetailsConstantData, function() {
    if (this.AssociationId == value && this.uniqueChargeAttr == uniqueChargeAttr) {
        //in this context: "this" refers to the currently selected 
        //item of the iteration over: 
        //  privateVariables.arrAllDetailsConstantData
    } else {
        $.each(arrAllDetails, function() {
            // in this context: "this" refers to the selected item
            // of the iteration over "arrAllDetails"
        });
    }
});
```

You can preserve the context when entering an iteration by binding `this` to a local variable.

```
$.each(privateVariables.arrAllDetailsConstantData, function() {
    if (this.AssociationId == value && this.uniqueChargeAttr == uniqueChargeAttr) {
        // this refers to an item from privateVariables.arrAllDetailsConstantData
    } else {
        var context = this;
        $.each(arrAllDetails, function() {
            // context refers to an item from privateVariables.arrAllDetailsConstantData
            // so: use 
            context.AssociationId
            // instead of 
            this.AssociationId
        });
    }
});
```